# javascript window.close() is unexpectedly closing 2 tabs

Tags: javascript

I have a web page, which consists of html inside an iframe. This page calls

```
window.open(url,'_blank').focus();
```

to open a new tab, which allows the user to perform some oauth authentication, and then redirects back to my site, whereupon I want to close that tab, and navigate back in the originating tab to the same place, as though I had never opened a tab in the first place.

To manage this I have the following code, which is basically saying "**if I am in a tab that was opened, send a message to the opening window with navigation information, and then close**"

```
  if (window.parent.opener)
                {
                  let data = {"for":"mywindow", "operation":"navigate","code":this.code, "state":this.state};
                  //handle this message in the message handler component, and redirect here on the original window
                  window.parent.opener.postMessage(data);
                  window.parent.close();
                }
```

Now, in most environments this works perfectly well. However in some environments it is closing not just the opened tab, but also the original tab.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the originating tab from closing?

Note that the code calls **window.parent** because of the complication that all the code is executing inside an i-frame.

**Update to the question**

I have reconfigured the code like so:

```
 if (window.parent.opener && window.parent!=window)
                {
                  let data = {"for":"mywindow", "operation":"navigate","code":this.code, "state":this.state};
                  //handle this message in the message handler component, and redirect here on the original window
                  window.parent.opener.postMessage(data);
                  window.parent.close();
                }
```

And the issue is still happening on a few clients!

Comment: Have you tried adding an extra condition to your if statement? `window.parent.opener && window.parent !== window`. This way you guarantee that the code will only be executed if this is not the parent window.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of doing this, although in all honesty I can't see why this would be a problem only in certain environments. The other thought I had was maybe using a timer to call the close() function

Comment: `if (window.parent.opener)` - why is `parent` involved here? You opened a new window/tab, in which all of this is happening, no? Then that window will have an opener, but why should it have a _parent_? It is not an iframe/frame itself. And MDN says, _"If a window does not have a parent, its parent property is a reference to itself."_ - I am guessing that might have something to do with your problem? (If you are executing the above code in more than one place.)

Comment: @CBroe, the auth site doesn't have an iFrame, but it redirects back to my web page and hits the code that is inside the iFrame, but the same code will also be hit in the original tab when it redirects, so perhaps this is the problem (although in that tab the window.parent.opener should be false)

Comment: Kinda odd that this problem only occurs on some environments. I tried to reproduce  and had no success. When you say environment, what do you mean exactly? An specific operating system? An specific browser?

Comment: @Matheus - on some customer sites. Puzzlingly it failed across Chrome, Edge and Firefox

Comment: Sounds like a bit overcomplicated design. Oauth can be done with redirection flow without the necessity of opening iframes. Can't you just do It via simple flow?

Comment: @Marek the iFrame isn't there to help the oAuth, we need it for other reasons